# Python multiple list max()

Tags: string, python-3.x, list, max

In python, I have a list full of strings and I want it to find the max by length. If there are some strings that share the same length them print out both. I have that but it does not seem to work

```
if len(in_list)>1:
  while len(in_list) == a:
    a = max(in_list, key=len)
    print("Pair", pair,":", a)
    in_list.remove(a)

elif len(in_list)<1:
  print("Pair", pair, ": No Common Sequence Found")
```

Comment: What were you trying to do with `while len(in_list) == a`?

Comment: I dont know, exactly. Im new at this but im just trying to get the max value of a string. If two elements of the string share the same length, them i want it to print out both. does that make sense? oh the pair is for a loop that I made

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a list of strings:

```
# word strings -> string to create a three way tie:

strings = "In python I have a list full of string and I want it to find the max by length".split()
```

We can go terse and reasonably efficient:

```
maxlen = max(len(s) for s in strings)

longest = filter(lambda s: len(s) == maxlen, strings)

print(list(longest))
```

But that efficiency is more due to pushing things down to the **C** level than due to a good algorithm as we walked the list of strings ***twice*** when we only need to walk it ***once***:

```
longest = strings[:1]
length = len(longest)

for string in strings:
    string_length = len(string)

    if string_length >= length:

        if string_length > length:
            longest = []
            length = string_length

        longest.append(string)

print(longest)
```

In a compiled language, this more verbose approach would likely be faster as it avoids repeating things.  If/when we want some elegance and some speed, that cries out for a dictionary:

```
counter = {}

for string in strings:
    counter.setdefault(len(string), []).append(string)

longest = counter[max(counter)]

print(longest)
```

In all three cases we get back:

```
['python', 'string', 'length']
```

Answer (score 1):

Given `strings`:

```
maxes = [string for string in strings if len(string) == max(map(len, strings))]
```

More readably (and this method is a lot more efficient; thanks to Shadow Ranger for pointing that out):

```
maxlen = max(len(s) for s in strings)
maxes = [string for string in strings if len(string) == maxlen]
```

This returns all strings if their length is the same as the length of the longest string.

Comment: Note: The "more  readable version" (which could still use `map`, just on the previous line) is also *far* more efficient; inlining the `max` computation in the conditional would recompute it every time, turning `O(n)` work into `O(n**2)` work. Python doesn't optimize that sort of thing for you.

Comment: @ShadowRanger That is true as well. I'll write that in just as a side note. I come from PPCG where efficiency is irrelevant most of the time ;) :P